# How recursion works in binary tree traversal in the below code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

```
void printPreorder(Node node)
{ 
    if (node == null) return; 
     System.out.print(node.key + " "); 
     printPreorder(node.left); 
     printPreorder(node.right);
}
```

Please explain the flow of the program

Comment: You debugger is best equipped to help you with this one.

Comment: Please explain what is not clear to you about the flow of the program. Aren't method calls self-explanatory?

Comment: Create a test example with distinct values and use the debugger in order to understand what happens and in which order.

Comment: So,  we are supposed to solve your homework questions?

Comment: @RealSkeptic if you think you are a big shot in java...then plz dont think so. I had a query because of which i had posted the query here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can tell from the line `printPreorder(node.left)` the tree is first traversed on the left-side of the tree. As soon as there is no more node on the left, the next call will be `printPreorder(null)`. This will cause the code to just return out of the `printPreorder(node.left)`.

Then it will execute the next statement, which is `printPreorder(node.right)`. Meaning it prints one node to the right, assuming this node is not null, it will once again fall into the `printPreorder(node.left)` and continue down the path until it reaches another 'null'.

Priting in pre-order always prints the most left-nodes first. And then the corresponding right-nodes afterwards.

This image might help you understand it better (taken from lylib.com/books/2/264/1/html/2/images/fig21-11.jpg).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you clear explanation. I am much grateful to you.

Comment: @PiyushMishra You're welcome! If this answer is good enough for you, consider accepting it as the correct answer :-)